# Redirecting a mobile site url with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a url so that it adds a url variable to all requests to the a sub-domain.

Example:

m.mydomain.com ==> m.mydomain.com?mobileFormat=true

This is the flag that triggers the mobile version of my site to load.

Should be easy right? Everything I have tried so far isn't working.

Here is the code I currently have in my .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ /index.cfm%{REQUEST_URI} [PT]

   RewriteRule ^locale/([^/]*)$ /?siteLocale=$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  m.%1/$1?mobileFormat=true [QSA]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, it would even be better since there are several domain aliases if it worked like this: m.[anydomainalias] ==> m.[anydomainalias]?mobileFormat=true

Comment: Can you give examples of what you've tried and how you've tried it.

Comment: Honestly, I think what you have here is close and is exactly what I am trying to do, but I can't see what the issue is that is causing it to error out. I just don't know enough about mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|jpg|gif|png|js|css)$
RewriteRule .? $1?mobileFormat=true [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Excellent - the smaller the solution the better. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\. [NC] will also work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is what you've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  m.%1/$1?mobileFormat=true [QSA]
```

QSA is Query String Append - if the URL they are trying to get to is:

```
m.mydomain.com?test=yes
```

then the above will rewrite this to:

```
m.mydomain.com?mobileFormat=true&test=yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. I added what I have in my htaccess file to the original post.

Comment: Any ideas? Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Maybe we could do something simpler for now, like: m.example.com ==> m.example.com/?mobileFormat=true

Comment: Looking at your rules here, there's some obvious flaws, but perhaps if you give me an idea of what index.cfm does, and what you are trying to do overall, I can give you a more comprehensive and conclusive answer :)

Comment: The first rule is inserted automatically by my CMS. The second one sets the international version of the site. Both of those work correctly. The CMS is using CFML as a server side language and all pages are processed through the index page (index.cfm). Does that help?